# Can't query date from MongoDB(Mlab) -- So simple but can't be solve

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mlab

After weeks of effort, I'm still having trouble querying the date field movie_datetime which has the structure below from Mlab using NodeJS.

```
"movie_datetime": {
        "$date": "2017-01-03T16:00:00.000Z"
},
"session_id": 31268
```

[image]

I tried the following

```
db.mycollection.find({
  "movie_datetime" : {"gte" : { "$date" : "2013-10-01T00:00:00.000Z"}}
})

db.mycollection.find({
    "movie_datetime" : {"$gte": new Date("2013-10-01T00:00:00.000Z")}
})

db.mycollection.find({
    "movie_datetime" : {"$gte": Date("2013-10-01T00:00:00.000Z")}
})

db.mycollection.find({
    "movie_datetime" : {"$gte": ISODate("2013-10-01T00:00:00.000Z")}
})
```

Appreciate any help.

**Current nodeJS Codes** :

**Tried variations of single quotes and doubles quotes and omitting .toISOString

```
var dateTime = '{"movie_datetime":{"$gte" : "'+new Date("2017-01-03T16:00:00.000Z").toISOString()+'"}}';

var dateTimeJson =JSON.parse(dateTimeVar);

db.mycollection.find(dateTimeJson);


Result for print dateTime 
{"movie_datetime":{"$gte" : "2017-01-03T16:00:00.000Z"}}

Result for print dateTimeJson 
{ movie_datetime: { '$gte': '2017-01-03T16:00:00.000Z' } }
```

***Node version 6.6.0***

Comment: Are you sure that you have inserted your document with `$date` as key?

Comment: The key is movie_datetime while $date is auto generated by mongoDB when my scraper inserts documents.

Comment: Can you show how exactly your document stored in mongodb?

Comment: Image attached in post above. Basically it's the same document structure I've shown.

Comment: Well, I think the dates stored in collections are of `string` data-type and not `date` type. So only string comparison will work.

Comment: I did test that string theory out but it did not work.

Comment: What context is this? You say you're running this in node.js, so are the example queries above actually in your application logic? Or are you using the `mongo` shell or the JSON editor in mLab's UI?

Comment: @pneumee The query is written in the nodeJS app. One observation is that the  $date field is created only in Mlab and not in Mongo Shell when an ISO date is inserted into a collection.

Comment: @Yang The `$date` field is simply a JSON representation of a BSON date object - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#date - mLab's UI uses a JSON editor, so all documents viewed & edited must follow strict JSON formatting. The `mongo` shell is JavaScript interpreter, so you can use expressions like `Date()` or `ISODate()` - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/shell-types/#date - That all said, the screenshot of your schema shows the field name as `date`, but your `find()` operations are querying on `movie_datetime`, which doesn't seem to be a valid field name.

Comment: @pneumee The date field that i've shown was from another document. I've editted the screenshot above. I still can't figure out what is wrong.

Comment: @Yang okay. In that case, something like `db.mycollection.find({ "movie_datetime" : {"$gte": new Date("2013-10-01T00:00:00.000Z")}
})` should work in node. If not, seems like something else is at play. (collection name incorrect for example?)

Comment: @pneumee That's what I did, codes seen above. It's definitely not a collection naming issue. I've got it working in Mongo Shell but not in NodeJS.

Comment: @Yang It looks like your current node logic is converting the date objects to strings for the query? If the `movie_datetime` values are stored as date objects, then you need to use date objects in your code to query against them. Mixing data types won't work.

Comment: @pneumee Do you have a sample solution? I've tried passing the ISODate() function along with the date into the db but it doesn't work either. I've tried all of the top answers from stackoverflow.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the mlab interface, it's actually like this:

```
{
    "createdAt": {
        "$gt": {
            "$date": "2017-11-08T20:05:45.866Z"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it.

```
db.myCollection.find({
  'movie_datetime.$date': {
    '$gte': new Date('2013-10-01T00:00:00.000Z')
  } 
});
```

edit - The picture you posted and the JSON you provided are different. For the picture it would be -

```
db.myCollection.find({
  'date.$date': {
    '$gte': new Date('2013-10-01T00:00:00.000Z')
  } 
});
```

Comment: db.myCollection.find({ "movie_datetime.$date" : {"$gte" : "new Date(2017-01-03T16:00:00.000Z)" } 
});

The query above doesn't work. The syntax is exactly what I wrote in NodeJs.

Comment: The picture i've posted is another document(updated to the right one). This isn't a field naming issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check the  [docs](http://docs.mlab.com/data-api/)

Dates are inserted in format given below

```
{"myDate": {"$date": "2010-07-20T23:23:50Z"}}
```